# javascript_importmap_tags: "undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

In rails 7, I have a javascript file set up as specified in the `importmap.rb` here:

`pin "best_in_place", to: "./vendor/gems/best_in_place-3.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts/best_in_place.js"`

This is included application.js as `import "best_in_place"`

However, it doesn't seem to find the file. It returns:

```
  undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass
```

from the line containing `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` in my application.js, which is the same error that the application gives when it doesn't find any file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the .js file to the `app/javascript` folder (specifically, a new folder called `app/javascript/src`), and referencing
`pin "best_in_place", to: "src/best_in_place.js"` worked for me.